# Kolmogorov–Smirnov (KS) two sample test interpretation

Tags: kolmogorov-smirnov-test

I am reading a paper which uses the KS two sample test to compare two signals: observed signal and predicted signal. The authors compute the test statistic  value and p-value, and set the critical value to 0.136 (200 samples, 5% significance level). They do comparisons for successive temporal windows. Most of statistic values are greater than the critical value and the P-values are very small. Hence, they reject the null hypothesis which is defined as "no difference between signals".
I am not familiar with statistical analysis, but we can conclude that the prediction in not reliable?

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "reliable:" please provide an actionable, quantifiable definition of what that is.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The authors just report: "We reject the null hypothesis". I do not understand if this is a good thing or not. Rejecting H0 hypothesis should mean that the observed (or ground-truth) signal is not sampled from the same distribution of the predicted signal, so they could be considered different in a certain way. Am I right? The task is to predict values as close as possible to the observed values (in the future).

Comment: You are correct--but this is a poor way to compare predicted values to observed values Rejecting the hypothesis simply means there are enough data in the window to reveal differences in the *univariate* distributions of the signal values, regardless of how well they might correspond.  Thus this test is likely to perform poorly in every sense: it can detect inconsequential changes (if enough data are put into each window) but it can fail to detect truly poor predictions, too!

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply!